# Visual C++ 2008 errors compiling simple file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, compiler-errors

I have a freshly installed copy of Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 express.

I have simple.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
```

I run this command:

```
cl.exe /c simple.cpp
```

And I get:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(189) : error C31
14: 'MustCheck': not a valid named attribute argument
        'MustCheck' must be a data member which is not static, const or literal
        or a property which is read-write and not static
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(189) : error C31
14: 'Null': not a valid named attribute argument
        'Null' must be a data member which is not static, const or literal
        or a property which is read-write and not static
```

Plus several screenfull more of errors.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstall MSVC. Rebooted. Reinstalled it. Rebooted. And now it works.